# How to Implement Runtime Toggle Features based on configuration

Tags: c++, configuration, arduino, esp8266

I am trying to implement what I think is called Feature Toggling with C++.

**Context**

This is for a Arduino/ESP8266 project developed with PlatformIO

**Desired Scenario**

User disables the Radio Communication in the configuration. The ESP8266 resets itself, reads the new config file and disables the Radio Communication Module.

**Problem**

It is easy not to instantiate the Radio class, but I don't want to have conditions deep in the app to check if the Radio class is instantiated.

**Question**

How to avoid feature toggle conditions deep in the application?

**Code Example**

```
// FMV.cpp
void FMV::setup() {
    this->connectionManager = new ConnectionManager(configController);
    this->connectionManager->setup();
}

// ConnectionManager.cpp
void ConnectionManager::setup()
{
    if (config.enableRadio)
    {
        this->radio = new Radio();
        this->radio->setup();
        delay(100);
    }
}

// FMV.cpp
void FMV::loop()
{
    // code

    // HOW TO AVOID THIS?
    if (this->connectionManager->radio != nullptr)
    {
        this->connectionManager->readRadioMessages();
    }

    // code 
}
```

Comment: Have two radio-classes inheriting from a common abstract base class. One is the proper radio-handling class, the other is just a dummy with functions that does nothing. If radio is enabled use the real class, else use the dummy do-nothing class. ***However*** this might lead to other problems down the line. For example if a function is expected to return some data, then you have to add checks for non-empty data instead.

Comment: As for the example code you show, IMO it's okay. It's explicit, easy to read and understand, and therefore easy to maintain. Using a solution like in my comment above might seem nice, but sooner or later it's going to be turning into a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The problem is that I have to check for the existence of the radio object in multiple places. This makes me think that it will become error prone very quickly.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, I believe it is not about "easy to read and understand" but more about programming 80 MHz microcontroller where a last minute-decision making costs a lot. Or is it not an issue?

Comment: @WindyFields The eps8266 will crash if I try to access a pointer that is null :) but currently I want my app to be easily configurable at runtime.

Comment: @WindyFields I didn't find such things to be a problem on a 7Mzh system with 0.5 MB of RAM back in the day.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, ok, I believe you)